# Load JavaScript when condition is true

Tags: php

How do I load a script if a PHP condition is true?

For example, I got an external script called `script.js` and I wanna load this if it's on the product page of WooCommerce.

I've tried the following but it doesn't work because it prints the code on the page:

```
<?php 
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'check_product_page' );

function check_product_page() {
   if(is_product()) {
      include ('script.js');
   }
}
?>
```

If I write the script inside a PHP like the below, it causes a fatal error:

```
<?php 

echo
'<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
   window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      //some code here...
   })
</script>';
?>
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is a useless problem description. If it worked, you likely wouldn't be here. It gives us no information to work with. What is the exact error you are getting (with stacktrace)? If there is no error, what behaviour are you getting, and what were you expecting to happen instead?

Comment: It's not working because your quotes are close by the `'load'`

Comment: @AntonyThompson Changed it to double quotes, but result is still the same.

Comment: Yup double qoutes won't work either. Let me post an answer which might suit you..

Comment: You should also check your error_logs, it will tell you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
<?php
if($condition == true){ 
  echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>';
}
?>
```

or:

```php
<?php if($condition == true): ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I've tried but the JavaScript has no effect. I guess it doesn't load.

Comment: PHP is compiled on the server so if you echo out this script tag, it will be available and loaded when the page is ready. Please check your dev tools console (F12) and see whether you have any errors and check if the script is present in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this works on my side, checkout maybe you have another issue:

```
    echo '<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
   window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      //some code here...
   })
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the single quotes are inside your string. You should actually do it the way which other people have shown, but if you need it to be an inline script you can do it like this:

```
<?php
   //some php can go here..
?>
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
   window.addEventListener("load", function() {
      //some code here...
   })
</script>
<?php //more php can go here... ?>
```